# Is Unit and Android unable to precisely follow a finger?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, touch, lag

I'm creating a Android game with Unity and I'm trying to make an object to follow my finger. This is the code I'm using.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++)
    {
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.touches[i].position), Vector2.zero);

        Vector3 touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.touches[i].position);

        if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Moved && hit.collider != null)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector2(touchPosition.x, touchPosition.y + sizeY);
        }
    }
```

I put the collider bellow the object and I added the size of the object to the Y, so it appears above my finger.
The problem is that if I move my finger slightly faster, I lose the object, that stays behind. Since the object lags behind, if I move my finger faster I end up out of the collider area and the object just stop moving.
The only way I found that works is to get rid of the Raycast thing and make the object follow the touch anywhere in the screen (I don't like that).

I just want to know if this is the best I can get from Unity and Android or if there a is way to make an object follow the finger in a one-by-one movement, with precision, without lag.
I'm testing on a Samsung Galaxy S8 just with the object and nothing else.

Comment: The problem is probably that the framerate of the game on your device is insufficient to keep up with your finger movements through continual raycasts. Can you explain why following the finger directly is an inadequate solution for you? That might help in devising a more reliable approach for your situation.

Comment: In fact it is not that important. I'm just learning and this is the second project I'm trying. For the first project I just give up on that kind of precision, but this time I decided to verify if there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not alone with this issue. Unity's Input API is frame-rate based and may not keep with the speed of the touch movement on the screen. If you're working on something that requires fast response based on the touch on the screen, use the new Unity's [InputSystem](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/InputSystem).  This API is still in experimental mode.

Its `Touchscreen` class can be used to access the touch on the screen. Your current code should translate into something like below:

```
public int touchIndex = 0;

void Update()
{
    Touchscreen touchscreen = UnityEngine.Experimental.Input.Touchscreen.current;

    if (touchscreen.allTouchControls[touchIndex].ReadValue().phase != PointerPhase.None &&
               touchscreen.allTouchControls[touchIndex].ReadValue().phase == PointerPhase.Moved)
    {
        Vector2 touchLocation = touchscreen.allTouchControls[touchIndex].ReadValue().position;   
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touchLocation), Vector2.zero);    
        Vector3 touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touchLocation);
        transform.position = new Vector2(touchPosition.x, touchPosition.y + sizeY);   
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm just a newbie with coding, C# and Unity, I don't think I should try that right now. Too many basic stuff to be learnt. Taking what you said, I'll consider that the answer to my question is YES, at least for now. 
Thank you again.

Comment: No problem. You can always come back when you think you're comfortable with C#